# Border of p-table is not showing in local project while running on browser

Tags: angular, primeng

```
.ui-table .ui-table-thead>tr>th.ui-resizable-column,
    .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr>td.ui-resizable-column {
        border-collapse: separate;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
```

to override the css
But it's not working. Any suggestions.

***I am using angular 8***

Comment: Are you want to give border to whole table?

Answer (score 0):

To override any styles in primeng. You have to use `:host::ng-deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead>tr>th.ui-resizable-column,
    .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr>td.ui-resizable-column {
        border-collapse: separate;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
```

in some cases simple over riding will also help

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table table {
  border-collapse: separate;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Depends on your need. Please try the above method. Hope it will help

Comment: Sorry do you want to change border for your entire table or just head element?

Comment: If you can let me know your clear requirements. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks